# Unable to startx with non-root user (Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied))

Tags: x11, gentoo

I'm unable to `startx` without root permissions, as it throws me this error:

```
parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (permission denied)
```

When I run `startx` as root, either with `sudo` or by `login`, it works perfectly fine. I am currently running Gentoo Linux.

- I've added the user I want to `startx` with to the `tty` group
- I've added read and write permissions to `tty0` for the `tty` group
- I've deleted my `.Xauthority` file.

I've been trying to figure out this issue for about a day, and literally every single forum post I've come across has been of absolutely no use to me. Can I please get some help with this?

Comment: Please append output of ```loginctl``` to your question.

Comment: @dirdi my installation that had this issue doesn't exist anymore, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

From the Gentoo Wiki, [running the elogind service](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Non_root_Xorg) solved my problem.

Comment: wait, how are you able to edit what i've said?

Comment: Many parts of SE can be confusing when starting out! Maybe start with [our tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), then hit some of the [Help Pages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help), in particular the [one on editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Welcome to U&L!

Comment: Despite already using Gentoo with elogind, I started hitting this tty0 permission error in 2023 when running `startx` as a non-root user.  Ultimately I fixed it by switching to `startx -- vt1`, using an alias in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution that worked for me. I had to restart some services while troubleshooting something, and it turned out elogind wanted a kick too